# BottomSheet body not being populated properly

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

I am trying to create a bottom sheet that expands to show a nested scroll view containing text.

I am creating this within a fragment and got several layers of layouts with the parent layout for the fragment:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.MyFragment">

    <com.google.ar.sceneform.SceneView
        android:id="@+id/myfragment_sceneview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/fullBlack" />

    <include layout="@layout/item_sheet" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The item_sheet is my bottom sheet and contains a header and a body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_sheet"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/bottom_sheet_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/bottom_sheet_peek_height"
    app:behavior_skipCollapsed="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/stall_fragment">

    <include layout="@layout/item_header" />
    <include layout="@layout/item_description_body" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Item header:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_sheet_peek_height"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_frame"
    android:divider="@drawable/material_divider"
    android:elevation="@dimen/material_elevation"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:outlineProvider="background"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/bottom_sheet_horizontal_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/bottom_sheet_horizontal_padding"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    tools:showIn="@layout/item_sheet">

    <bunch of TextView views>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my bottom sheet body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bottom_sheet_bgc"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/bottom_sheet_horizontal_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/bottom_sheet_horizontal_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/material_unit_1"
    tools:showIn="@layout/item_sheet">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/fullBlack"
            tools:text="@string/item_description" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

I am initializing this in my fragment using:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false)
        return view
    }
```

**When I run the above code, the bottom header renders properly, but when I expand I get an empty body. Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be my usage of development tag `tools:text` when I should have used `android:text`